# C++ Boost.Program_options Features

Tags: c++, boost

I´m considering using Boost.Program_options to parse command lines in c++. Right now, I´m a complete newbie in c++, so I would appreciate some patience :-)
I don´t even know how to "add reference" to this library in my project, but I will figure it out later by myself.

I have read Boost.Program_options tutorial, but I´m not sure if it is suitable to all requirements my program needs. Actually, I´m 90% sure I´m going to use it, but I would like someone with more experience to give me 100% sure.

So, my requirements are:

```
1) myprogram -mode1
2) myprogram -mode1 filePathWithBlankSpaces
3) myprogram
4) myprogram -mode2 filePathWithBlankSpaces
5) myprogram -mode1 filePathWithBlankSpaces -parameter1 doubleValueOfTheParameter
6) myprogram -help
7) myprogram -mode3 parameter1 parameter2 parameter3 parameter4
8) myprogram -mode4
```

obs:
filePathWithBlankSpaces, parameterX and doubleValueOfTheParameter are parameters.

My main concern is with requirements 2,5 and 7.

Comment: -1. are you asking to read documentation for you? thanks but no.

Comment: 7) is problematic.  I think you would need to say `myprogram -mode3 "p1 p2 p3 p4"`  -- that is, add quotes around the parameters.  Given your requirements, it would not be hard to write your own command line parser.

Comment: boost program_options follows pretty much unix conventions, so blank spaces is not a problem as long as the string is enclosed in quotation marks, `double` is supported, and `std::vector` is supported. So what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If your question is simply "is `boost::program_options` suitable for my needs" alias "can I write a program with call options, also with multiple arguments", the answer is absolutely **yes**.

If you are asking how is it done, ask it, and I'll edit this answer for you.